# Mobile supporting websites

Tags: html, mobile, mobile-website

I want to build mobile supporting website. I googled abt it and discovered some tools that can do this, some suggested to use xhtml-mp, WML... can anybody suggest me which is the best and optimized way to build mobile supporting website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can see datails about @rotara method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844020/way-to-do-content-adaptation-to-mobile

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best and most stable way to do this is to have an eye on the mobile devices already at the time of creating your website.

If i have to do such a task, i would write my website as usual and then create different CSS Styles for the different devices like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="website.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="handheld" href="mobile_website.css">
```

That's the way i would do it.

Comment: Actually most mobile browsers don't support the media type `handheld`. CSS3 Media Queries have wider support.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use any special markup for mobile sites. Use normal HTML (4.01 or 5 your choice).

As Chris hints at, depending on the complexity of your site, often you don't need any extra site for mobile browsers, just apply different styles to your HTML using [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).